# SFML repeating event loop 3 times per game loop

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

I have no clue why this is happening, I checked using a console output each time the event loop is ran. All this means is that animation is messed up, I could probably use a temporary fix but I am really just curious why this happens.

Comment: There is not much to go on. Its hard to look for bugs without any code to look at. Can you post a minimal version that includes the behaviour?

Comment: You have two problems.  The first is on line 25.  The next one is online 1350.  Fix these issues, then use a debugger to validate your fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use code similar to the example code, you're running a `while()` loop for the event loop, which poll events as long as there are events and thus it "repeats" as often as there have been events triggered. Events can range from mouse moving, to click, to keyboard input, to window focus, etc. Look at the official documentation to see all of them.

Now if the iteration of the event loop is messing up your rendering or animation, you're doing it wrong. Run your updates directly in the game loop and not the event loop. If you need some information from events, cache them by storing them in some variables.

And last but not least, as the commentators said, learn how to properly ask for help.